# CSS not being applied to HTML

Tags: html, css, apache2

I pretty much have the simplest thing set up and it refuses to work for whatever reason. The HTML document refuses to pick up on the CSS. If you View Source and click on the href attribute on line 6, it shows me the file so I know the browser can see it. I am about to lose my mind here.

Here's what is rendered.

[image: Stupid output...]

And here's the code.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/master.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    test
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    background: orange;
}
```

I thought maybe its a server issue so here's the apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName adtest.dev

    DocumentRoot /var/www/adtest.dev/
    <Directory /var/www/adtest.dev/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/adtest.dev/error.log

    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/adtest.dev/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and here's the output of `ls -Rn`

```
/var/www/adtest.dev$ ls -Rn
.:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000 4096 May 18 19:06 css
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  204 May 18 19:06 index.html

./css:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 33 May 18 19:06 master.css
```

I am obviously missing something super easy, right?

When visiting the site while `tail -f /var/log/apache2/adtest.dev/access.log` is running. I get only 1 line.

```
[18/May/2014:19:28:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0"
```

If I go directly to the css file, i get

```
[18/May/2014:19:44:58 +0000] "GET /css/master.css HTTP/1.1" 200 314 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0"
```

The error log remains empty.

Comment: Just a suggestion from the top of my head - have you tried changing the href to `css/master.css`?

Comment: Are you sure your css file is in your root directory, and not the web root's directory? Looks like someone just beat me to it!

Comment: @AndersG: nothing changes. @user2356315: that is why I posted the output of `ls`.

Comment: What do your server logs say?

Comment: Also, pure speculation, but I just checked the `DocumentRoot` directive on one of my servers, and it has no trailing `/`, while yours does. Maybe try removing that?

Comment: You mentioned that you can click on the href from view source, does that imply that if you go to `adtest.dev/css/master.css` in your browser, you see the contents of the file?

Comment: @ApisUtilis: [18/May/2014:19:28:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0" is the access log line. The error log was empty. And yes, FF and Chrome show me the contents of the file.

Comment: @merlin2011: removed the trailing slash from `DocumentRoot`. no changes :/

Comment: That log message is showing a 200 response on the home page (i.e., not an error). Are you perhaps forgetting to reload the server to make sure that it is not serving you an old copy of the html file after removing that leading slash (which really looks like it would cause the problem you're seeing)? Other than that, I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: @ApisUtilis I greatly appreciate you taking the time to help. Not sure if you've seen the edit but the problem was adBlock stopping me from doing anything because i had the word 'ad' in the domain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was caused by AdBlock. In the default rules, they have `/adtest.` which picked up on my test domain `http://adtest.dev`.

Either removing that rule from AdBlock or renaming my test domain to just 'test.dev' resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a problem with the path to the CSS. I just did an experiment where I put them in the same directory and changed the path to just `master.css` and it worked perfectly fine, so there's no issue with either the HTML or CSS.

With your current path of `/css/master.css`, your `master.css` must be in a directory called `css` directly under the web root.

You should try specifying a relative path and see if that fixes the issue, and then try debugging the absolute path.

For example, based on the file structure you have shown, and assuming that `index.html` is the relevant HTML file, just change the path to `css/master`. That is, deleting the leading `/`.

Comment: moving master.css back a directory and editing the reference changes nothing.

Comment: @castis, Did you remove the leading `/`?

Comment: removing the leading slash made no changes. i was however still able to see the contents of the file in the browser.

Comment: Although this did not ultimately solve the issue, I thank you very much for taking your time to help me with my problem.

Comment: @castis, You are welcome. It is a difficult issue to reproduce. :)